# $5 \frac {3}{*} \times 3 \frac {*}{2}=19$?

Tags: arithmetic

One of my friends gave me this apparently easy-looking problem which I do not know how to crack. The problem is to find the values of   "*" where

$$5 \frac {3}{*} \times 3 \frac {*}{2}=19\text{ ?}$$

I can rearrange the problem as $5 \frac {3}{x} \times 3 \frac {y}{2}=19$ and I have to find the values of $x,y.$  Now $5 \frac {3}{x} \times 3 \frac {y}{2}=19 \implies \frac {5x+3}{x} \times \frac {6+y}{2}=19.$ Now, I do not know which way to  go?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT:** Here "*"-s are not same. Infact I know the answer but do not know how to get it. Here $x=7,y=1.$

Comment: If $*$ is not the same, how about naming them just $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The question was exactly what I posted.I did not know how to express it otherwise.

Comment: You *do* know how to express it otherwise--that's what you did when you "rearranged" the problem. Inform your friend that (s)he shouldn't use one variable to mean two separate things at the same time.

Comment: It surely has been a mistake from his part. To eliminate the confusion about "*" I said in the question  "find the values of..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume $x, y$ are supposed to be positive integers (otherwise there are infinitely many real solutions for $x, y$). If $y \geq 2$, then $19=(5+\frac{3}{x})(3+\frac{y}{2})>5(3+\frac{2}{2})=20$, a contradiction. Thus $y=1$, so $x=7$.

Comment: clever:) But,how did you know that $y\not\ge2$ before hand?

Comment: $5+\frac{3}{x}>5$, so $3+\frac{y}{2}$ can't be too large.

Comment: As $5+\frac3x>5, 3+\frac y2<\frac{19}5\implies y<\frac85\implies y=1$ as $y>0$

Comment: Hmm yes that would probably have been a nicer way to phrase the argument so that it doesn't involve a proof by contradiction. I'll just leave it as it is though, since it is quite concise now anyway.

Answer (score 3):

On simplification,  $y=\frac{8x-18}{5x+3}$

Now, $$8(5x+3)-5(8x-18)=114$$

So, $5x+3$ must divide $114$ and as $x>0, 5x+3>3$

Now the factors of $114$ are $1,2,3,6,19,38,57,114$

So,  $5x+3$ can be  $6,19,38,57,114$

$6\equiv1\pmod 5,19\equiv4, 38\equiv3,57\equiv2,114\equiv4$

So,  $5x+3$ can be $38\implies x=7,y=1$